# Will pdb files generated on one windows machine work on another windows machine

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, pdb-files

I'm implementing a simple c++ profiler to find the function execution time.
I'm using visual studio 2017 to build my application. I've set _penter & _pexit hooks and trying to get the function name from the address when the hooked methods are invoed.

I'm able to get the function name when I run the application in the same machine in which I build the applicatioin. But it doesn't work when I copyand run it on another machine. When I checked GetLastError() error it showed the error "Attempt to access invalid address". I spent some time and found that this happens because of the pdb file. If I build the application on the other machine then it works.

Below is the code which I'm using to get the function name from the address

```
    TCHAR  buffer[sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) + MAX_SYM_NAME * sizeof(TCHAR)] ;
    memset(&buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
    PSYMBOL_INFO    pSymbolInfo = ( PSYMBOL_INFO)buffer;
    pSymbolInfo->SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) ;
    pSymbolInfo->MaxNameLen = MAX_SYM_NAME;
    BOOL bResult = SymFromAddr(GetCurrentProcess(), (DWORD64)pa, &symDisplacement, pSymbolInfo);
```

Please help me to understand the issue in the above case. Will the pdb file generated on one machine will not support/work in another machine? If no, how should I build the application with pdb file to work on all machines.

Comment: The pdbs are valid for the dlls you built, a different machine should make no difference, when matching pdbs to dlls, the original build path does not need to match in order for the pdbs to match, the dlls and pdbs have a GUID that is checked to see if they [match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/debugging-with-symbols#how-symchk-works)

Comment: Thanks.
But, I tried few things and found that the pdb file works for me only when I put it in the same path(created a folder in copied machine) in which I built the application.

In the copied machine I'm getting the profiled function name as "?GetRuntimeClass@CMFCAppProfilerView@@UEBAPEAUCRuntimeClass@@XZ" But in the build machine it returns "CMFCAppProfilerView::GetRuntimeClass".
I'm not sure what makes this difference.